# SSL Certificate

Tags: ssl, openssl

I am building a buy-system and i was told to set up an SSL certificate on my web-server to work with bank operations.

I am new to this and i don't exactly understand the difference between OpenSSL (which is free and opensourced) and SSL certificates, that are needed to be bought (thawte.com).

I guess OpenSSL is smth like tool to create a keys (ive alredy done this for firstdata.com), but if i buy ssl certificate on thawte.com and install it ill have my web-site running over https?

Can i use free openSSL to work with banks? Or i have to buy one?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The biggest difference between a self-issued (with OpenSSL) certificate and one you buy from thawte (or somewhere else) is that of **trust**. If you want your users to use access your ssl enabled website without being prompted for "do you trust the certificate from this issuer?" you need to buy a certificate from a [trusted certification authority](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_authority), such as [thawte or one of the others](http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Security/Public_Key_Infrastructure/PKIX/Tools_and_Services/Third_Party_Certificate_Authorities/).

Your website will run over https with any old x.509 certificate so if you only have a few people accessing your ssl site you may convince them to trust your self-issued certificate and save the money for the certificate.

Comment: so the 'https' on both sites: mine and the bank's - means, that we have a secured connection between us? 


And in the case of firstdata, when i've just generated the key, the thing was that the key role is just to compare who from the data was sent?

Answer (score 5):

OpenSSL is a tool and a library that can be used to generate certificate requests (CSR), self-signed certificates and issue certificates from a CA (if it's a CA you control of course).

There are a number of pre-trusted certification authorities embedded in most browsers. They issue certificates by signing the certificate they give you (coming from your certificate request). In turn, the certificates they issue can be verified by your users' browsers against their (issuing) CA certificate because it's shipped with them by default.

You can generate your own CA and issue certificates yourself, but the problem is that your CA certificate won't be trusted by default in most browsers, so it's worthless unless you make your users import it explicitly (which is fine for corporate CAs for example, but is impractical in general). A self-signed certificate is a special case of this: it's the root CA certificate you generate or a one-off certificate for a given machine; either way, you'd have to import it explicitly.

Some pre-trusted CAs will let you use OpenSSL to generate the certificate request as part of their procedure, but they may also offer other procedures relying on other tools. Which tool you or they use doesn't really matter. What you want is a certificate issued by a CA your remote party will trust.

Answer (score 1):

You can sign up for free and generate free SSL certificate for your web site, at least for the first year, on [StartSSL](https://www.startssl.com/). Their site shows Weekend Maintenance now, but it will be available later. I was able to get free SSL certificate from them. This certificate is signed by Startcom certification authority which is [trusted, according to their site](http://www.startcom.org/?app=14&rel=33).